# How to achieve an uncertain score rule in Optaplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner to develop a system, it similars with the example - MeetingScheduling. Assigns some tasks to some machines and determine the start time. I create a class - TaskAssignment as the planning entity, the fields - "machine" and "startTimeGrain" as the planning variables.

But in my use case,  there is a constraint doesn't exist in MeetingScheduling, I don't know how to achieve. In some cases, possibly there is a preparation time on the front of the task. It means, TaskA and TaskB is the contiguous tasks on the same machine, TaskB is not going to start until TaskA finished (TaskA is the previous task of TaskB), and possibly there is the preparation time between those tasks, means that after TaskA finished, TaskA have to wait for a while to start, but how long to wait is not fixed, it depends on its previous task.

```
Possibly like following:
TaskA -> TaskB: TaskB's preparation time is 5 mins.
TaskC -> TaskB: TaskB's preparation time is 15 mins.
TaskC -> TaskA: TaskA's preparation time is 0 min.
```

So. I get the preparation time for the task base on its previous task (read it from a list)  and calculate the interval between two tasks. if the interval is less than preparation time, interval minus preparation time as the punish score.
When I run planning, the rule through a Score Corruption exception.   I found that the reason is that both the interval and preparation time are uncertain.

For the interval, it depends on the previous task's end time and its own task's start time, the start time is the planning variable, so it's uncertain.

For the preparation time, there is a preparation time list in each task, which preparation time is available depends on this previous task, due to the start time is keep changing during planning, the preparation time keeps changing too. so preparation time is uncertain too.
in this case, is any way to achieve?
Many thanks

Here is my rule, but score corruption exception appear.

```
rule "Make sure interval large than preparation time"
salience 1
    when
        $currentTA : TaskAssignment(
            $machine: machine != null, 
            startingTimeGrain != null,
            $lack : getIntervalLack() < 0L // in getIntervalLack(), interval minus preparation time
            ) 
    then
            scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  $lack);
end
```

The exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption: the workingScore (-17hard/0medium/0soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-20hard/0medium/0soft) after completedAction ([TaskAssignment-5 {Machine-1([023]) -> Machine-1([023])}, TaskAssignment-5 {TimeGrain-2 -> TimeGrain-2}]):
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
    com.esquel.configuration/Make sure interval large than preparation time/[TaskAssignment-4]=-3hard/0medium/0soft
  Check your score constraints.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:496)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(DefaultSolverScope.java:132)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractPhaseScope.java:167)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.processMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:140)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.doMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:126)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:74)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:167)
    at com.esquel.main.App.startPlan(App.java:94)
    at com.esquel.main.App.main(App.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hard constraint, I 'd make it build in and do it with a shadow variable:

I'd probably pre-calculate the task dependencies, so taskB has a reference to it's `potentioalPrecedingTasks` (taskA and taskC in your example). Then I 'd use the "chained through time" pattern (see docs) to determine the order in which the tasks get executed. Based on that order, **the starting time is a shadow variable** that is `actualPrecedingTask.endingTime + lookUpPreperationTime(precedingTask, thisTask)`. See arrivalTime listener in VRP, same principle.

If it's a soft constraint, I 'd still have that same shadow variable, but call it desiredStartingTime and add a soft constraint to check if the real startingTime is equal or higher than the desiredStartingTime.

Comment: Yes, it's a hard constraint.
I had tried the "chained through time" pattern, but there are other constraints that the pattern could not achieve, look at my description in the answer following.

Comment: In any case, even if a better design of your app (which I won't get into here) would avoid your score corruption, OptaPlanner should somewhere list the common reasons for score corruption, so you can figure out what's wrong. Let me think about that.

Comment: Thanks, Geoffrey. Do you mean, the uncertain score calculation may not be the cause of the score corruption?

Answer (score 0):

Background summary: Some orders are sent to the production workshop, an order is split into multiple tasks in a sequence by the process routing. The tasks of an order must be executed in the sequence. Each task can only be executed on a particular machine. There is maybe preparation time before starting a task, whether the preparation time exists or not, and it is long or short, depends on what task at the front of it on the same machine. 
The following are the main constraints what hard to implement:

```
Hard constraints:
1. A task must be executed by the particular machine.
2. Tasks in an order must be executed by a particular sequence (tasks of an order, come from the processes of the order, usually they need to be executed by different machine).
3. The first task of an order has the earliest start time. It means when the order arrived the production workshop.
4. Some tasks in an order maybe have a request start time, means if the previous task finish, the next task has to start in a period. For example, TaskA is the previous task of TaskB in the same order, TaskB has to start in 16 hours after TaskA finish.
5. A task probably has a preparation time, depends on its previous task of in the same machine(usually, the same process from different order were assigned to the same machine). If there is the preparation time on the task, the task has to start after the preparation time. In other words, there is an interval between these tasks.
Soft constraints:
1. All task should be executed as soon as possible.
2. Minimize the preparation time, due to the different location of the tasks lead to the different relationship of the tasks, then the preparation times are different.
```

So, here are two "chains" in the solution during planning. Optaplanner generated a chain for the tasks in the same machine. The another "chain" comes from the order, and in this "chain", tasks will be assigned to the different machine. Two "Chains" 
were hang together.

I named that the chain in a machine (generated by Optaplanner) as "Machine chain", and the "chain" in an order as "Order chain".

Now, you can see, due to two "Chains" were hang together, a task as the node both in the Machine chain and Order chain.

I had tried the "chained through time" pattern, the undoMove corruption appeared.  I think the reason is when I updated a task in Machine chain, the following task in the same Machine chain will be updated too, these tasks are the nodes of Order chains,   a chain reaction broke out.

I think my case looks like the example - Project Job Scheduling. But the difference is two "Chains" in this example never hang together.

So, I try the simple patter, but I can't escape the Score Corruption exception.